# ViewModelProvider is causing the crash as soon as fragment is opened. How do I resolve this?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, mobile-application, android-mvvm

I am making a note app with Room Database but the line `noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)` in `AddFragment.kt` is making my app crash as soon as the `AddFragment` is opened. To view the full code find the github repository link in the end.

Below is the full code for AddFragment.kt

```
class AddFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddBinding
    private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)


        //throwing error
        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val noteTitle: String = binding.addTitleText.text.toString().trim()
            val noteBody: String = binding.addNoteText.text.toString().trim()

            when {
                noteTitle.isEmpty() -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Title missing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    binding.addTitleText.requestFocus()
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                noteBody.isEmpty() -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Note Body missing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    binding.addNoteText.requestFocus()
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                else -> {
                    noteViewModel.insertNote(Note(noteTitle, noteBody))
                    Toast.makeText(this.activity, "New Note Added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
```

***crash report***

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.example.notezy.ViewModel.NoteViewModel
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:275)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150)
        at com.example.notezy.Fragments.AddFragment.onCreateView(AddFragment.kt:33)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267)
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.notezy.Fragments.AddFragment.onCreateView(AddFragment.kt:33) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.notezy.Database.NoteDatabase. NoteDatabase_Impl does not exist
        at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.java:94)
        at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.java:952)
        at com.example.notezy.Database.NoteDatabase$Companion.getDatabase(NoteDatabase.kt:24)
        at com.example.notezy.ViewModel.NoteViewModel.<init>(NoteViewModel.kt:18)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:267) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:187) 
        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
        at com.example.notezy.Fragments.AddFragment.onCreateView(AddFragment.kt:33) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2698) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:320) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2224) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1997) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1953) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1849) 
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:413) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

### ***Github Link for the Repo:*** [Click Here](https://github.com/013himanshu/Notezy)

Comment: ``ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)``

Comment: Sorry but the app still crashes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your real error is `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.notezy.Database.NoteDatabase` and to fix it you should :

1. add `id 'kotlin-kapt'` to your plugins in `build.gradle`
2. add `implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$rootProject.roomVersion"` dependency
3. replace `annotationProcessor` to `kapt` annotation for your `"androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"` dependecy

Happy Codding

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

The ViewModels (VMs) may theoretically be initialized as class level instance variables using the Kotlin extension library import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels method by viewmodels(). By initializing the VM as a class level instance var it can be accessed within the class.

```
class AddFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddBinding
    //private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel
     private val noteViewModel: NoteViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_add, container, false)


        //throwing error
        //noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val noteTitle: String = binding.addTitleText.text.toString().trim()
            val noteBody: String = binding.addNoteText.text.toString().trim()

            when {
                noteTitle.isEmpty() -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Title missing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    binding.addTitleText.requestFocus()
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                noteBody.isEmpty() -> {
                    Toast.makeText(this.activity, "Note Body missing.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    binding.addNoteText.requestFocus()
                    return@setOnClickListener
                }
                else -> {
                    noteViewModel.insertNote(Note(noteTitle, noteBody))
                    Toast.makeText(this.activity, "New Note Added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }

        return binding.root
    }
```

Comment: The crashing stops but then it won't insert the data into database.

Answer (score -1):

Don't do anything besides inflating your view in `onCreateView`. Move the view setup and view model use into `onViewCreated`.

In fact, Fragment's constructor allows you to pass the layout ID directly, so you should never have to override `onCreateView` at all. You can switch your binding factory method from `inflate` to `bind` to attach to the already-inflated view.

```
class AddFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_add) {
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentAddBinding
    private lateinit var noteViewModel: NoteViewModel

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view)

        noteViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(NoteViewModel::class.java)

        binding.addBtn.setOnClickListener {
            // ...
        }

        return binding.root
    }
}
```